# Issue with field validation?

Tags: php, forms, validation

I must be having a massive brain fart today...

I am trying to make sure that either a ZipCode, or a City is entered into the form

```
$zip = @$_POST['ZipCode'];
$city = @$_POST['City'];

// validate, at least zipcode and radius if not City/radius
$errMsg = '';
$valid = true;
$valCity = (isset($city) && strlen($city) > 0);
$valZip = (isset($zip) && strlen($zip) > 0);

if(!(!$valCity && $valZip) || ($valCity && !$valZip)){
    $errMsg .= '<p>Please make sure at least a city/town, or zip code is entered.</p>';
    $valid = false;
}
```

ZipCode only works, City only does not work.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is little bit more complicated than it needs to be, and you're using isset where you really need to use empty.

```
$zip = $_POST['ZipCode'];
$city = $_POST['City'];

// validate, at least zipcode and radius if not City/radius
$errMsg = '';
$valid = true;

if(empty($zip) && empty($city)){
    $errMsg .= '<p>Please make sure at least a city/town, or zip code is entered.</p>';
    $valid = false;
}
```

If both $zip and $city are empty, then the message will be set and $valid will become false.

The difference is that empty() will check the value of a variable, where isset() will check the presence of the variable, so by setting $zip and $city, whether they were null or not, isset() would always return true for them.

**-- UPDATE --**

Just FYI, empty will also check string length, so there's no need to do both.

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` is a little more complicated than it needs to be...

```
if(!($valCity || $valZip)){
    $errMsg .= '<p>Please make sure at least a city/town, or zip code is entered.</p>';
    $valid = false;
}
```

This says that both valCity and valZip need to be true.   If either is false, your message will display.

Comment: please see the question.  I need either/or... not both as required

Comment: Fixed...  your condition just needs to be an OR.   If either is true, this will work.

Comment: I did clarify exactly in the question, read it again and you will see `ZipCode only works, City only does not work. What am I doing wrong?`

Comment: The core problem is the code above, not the if statement, this approach won't help at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
if(!isset($zip) || !isset($city)){
    $errMsg = '<p>Please make sure at least a city/town, or zip code is entered.</p>';
    $valid = false;
}
```

And this:

```
$errMsg .=
```

Can rather be:

```
 $errMsg =
```

And doesn't have to be defined like this:

```
$errMsg = '';
```

Before the if function. At the top somewhere of your code.

Comment: isset() is the wrong function to be using here, unless you're using it on the $_POST variables.